# Why is scheduler overlooking <(..) notation in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, scheduled-tasks

I find using <(..) notation handy with cat or paste and have implemented it successfully in several shell scripts, but when I submit those scripts to an LSF scheduler, I tend to get an error from an unexpected ")", as if the "<(.." bit is being ignored.

Is it possible to include the <(..) trick with a simple fix? Also, does it have a name?

Comment: `<(...)` is a non-standard extension to shells like `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh`. Your scheduler may only support POSIX standard features.

Comment: It's a bash feature called [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). It won't work with plain sh.

Comment: I appreciate that there may not be a workaround, but I just wanted to thank you both for giving me further insight.